# Add a custom message for No Results Found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which is used to search a website. I need to add a message when there is no result found. Something very simple. "No Results Found"

How do I achieve this?

```
function search() {
var searchTerm = $.trim($("#search-text-input").val());
var path = $.url('path').toLowerCase();
if(searchTerm){
    if(!path.match('search.html$')){
        $(location).attr('href', pathPrefix + 'search.html?term='+searchTerm+'&path='+path);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#results').html('');
        $.each(pages, function(index, page){
            $.ajax( { url:page.url, success: function(result) {
                    page.content = result;
                    var pageResult = searchPage(page, searchTerm);
                    if(pageResult.length){
                        var line = $("<div><h2><a href='" + page.url + "'>" + page.title + "</a></h2><p>"+ pageResult.join("...<br/>") + "...</p></div>");
                        if(page.highlight) line.addClass('highlight-search');
                        line.appendTo("#results");
                    }
                }
            });
            }
        );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's the Java connection here? Why the Java tag?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - JAVA removed. Isn't this Javascript?

Comment: jQuery to be more specific

Comment: [What does Java have to do with Javascript](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/01/16/java-is-not-javascript-tell-your-friends/)?

Comment: @DylanB - Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - it's an oversight and has since been corrected.

Comment: Good, but please check the link as it helps to understand the difference (kind of like ham is to hamster)

Comment: Is THAT where ham comes from???? It all makes sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `else` statement to your `if(pageResult.length)` appending "No results found"...

```
if(pageResult.length){
    var line = $("<div><h2><a href='" + page.url + "'>" + page.title + "</a></h2><p>"+ pageResult.join("...<br/>") + "...</p></div>");
    if(page.highlight) line.addClass('highlight-search');
    line.appendTo("#results");
} else {
    var line = $("<div>No results found</div>");
    line.appendTo("#results");
}
```

Comment: Works in displaying the message, however It now displays the message at least 12 times.

Comment: Well, I think the user should understand by then!

Comment: It displays 12 times because it's in a loop for every page, a quick workaround would be to add a variable condition else if i==1 or something. Other than that you'd have to rethink your logic

Comment: If only I knew how. Thanks for the advice though